# put the user input inside the sql function when using python

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, user-input

I was hoping you can help me out with this one.

I am trying to insert data into an sql table using python . When I hard code, I have no issue. I want to use user input inside the sql query .

```
x=10
c.execute(''' INSERT INTO PARK_DB.dbo.gerversion (GerNr, Dateiname, ReleaseNr, UpdateNr, RevisionNr, Dat, Zusatz)
            VALUES            
            (x,'CODEREASY_7',7,4,2,getdate(),' ')
            ''')
```

How do I place the value of `"x"` inside the SQL query for example? 
How do I place a user input directly into the query without going through a variable

Thank you

Comment: You (or more likely someone else) will regret the use of 3 part names. The connection should determine the database context. This will be a hard lesson to learn if you ever try to change the database name or  use multiple environments in the same server instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `?` as a placeholder to bind a value into the T-SQL statement:

```
x = 10
sql = (
   "INSERT INTO PARK_DB.dbo.gerversion (GerNr, Dateiname, ReleaseNr, UpdateNr, RevisionNr, Dat, Zusatz) "+
   "VALUES(?, 'CODEREASY_7', 7, 4, 2, getdate(), ' ')"
)
c.execute(sql, (x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
x= int(input("Enter value"))

 ((x),'CODEREASY_7',7,4,2,getdate(),' ')
           ''')
```